# How does the .net core framework handle model binding on routes using the FromQuery attribute when the type has properties that are also classes?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

It seems obvious to me that a method that looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] SomeType data) {

}
```

where SomeType is:

```
public class SomeType {
    public int HowMany { get; set; }
    public string Why { get; set; }
}
```

Would be used by a url that looks like domain/controllerName?howMany=5&why=whoknows

But what if SomeType looks like this?

```
public class SomeLowerType {
    public int anotherThing { get; set; }
}

public class SomeType {
    public int HowMany { get; set; }
    public string Why { get; set; }
    public SomeLowerType Anotherhing { get; set;}
}
```

What would the url look like for that please? Struggling to find docs on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.` for nested properties, just as you would in code. That makes your example look like this:

```
domain/controllerName?howMany=5&why=whoknows&anotherhing.anotherThing=whatevs
```